# How to split an array of object with 5 properties to a 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ohlc

The below is my data that I get from an **API** and I want to **group it as time in one index** and the other values in another index. Is that possible to split this? I want the array to be in the format as the values in a second array format

**Api data**

```
0: (5) [1577080200000, 157.5599, 157.4902, 157.495, 78330]
1: (5) [1577080500000, 157.54, 157.485, 157.5128, 118202]
2: (5) [1577080800000, 157.54, 157.47, 157.48, 130805]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[1577080200000][157.5599, 157.4902, 157.495, 78330]
[1577080500000][157.54, 157.485, 157.5128, 118202]
[1577080800000][157.54, 157.47, 157.48, 130805]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why would you need one element (first element of the arrays) inside the array.

If you really want 2 separate arrays, one for the first element and one for the rest then just add an extra array wrapper around `[x[0]]`

```js
const arr = [
  [1577080200000, 157.5599, 157.4902, 157.495, 78330],
  [1577080500000, 157.54, 157.485, 157.5128, 118202],
  [1577080800000, 157.54, 157.47, 157.48, 130805],
]

const newArr = arr.map(x => [x[0],[...x.filter((y, i) => i !== 0)]
]);
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the array and take the first element and the rest for mapping.

```js
var data = [[1577080200000, 157.5599, 157.4902, 157.495, 78330], [1577080500000, 157.54, 157.485, 157.5128, 118202], [1577080800000, 157.54, 157.47, 157.48, 130805]],
    result = data.map(([first, ...rest]) => [[first], rest]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `splice`:

```js
const arr = [1577080200000, 157.5599, 157.4902, 157.495, 78330]
const traverseArr = [arr.splice(0,1),arr]

console.log(traverseArr)
```

Comment: you are mutating the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` method to flat array which will be created by the function:

```
const result = arr.flatMap(([a, b, c, d])=> [[a], [b, c, d]]);
```

An example:

```js
const arr = [
  [1577080200000, 157.5599, 157.4902, 157.495, 78330],
  [1577080500000, 157.54, 157.485, 157.5128, 118202],
  [1577080800000, 157.54, 157.47, 157.48, 130805],
]

const result = arr.flatMap(([a, b, c, d])=> [[a], [b, c, d]]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your results array that you mentioned is not a 2 dimensional array, the correct format of 2-dim array is:

```
[[1577080800000], [157.54, 157.47, 157.48, 130805]]
```

However, you can get your expected result in a two-dimensional array with the following code:

```
function splitArray(arr: any[]) {
    const first = arr.slice(0, 1);
    const tail = arr.slice(1);
    return [first, tail];
}
```

and then call the function like this:

```
splitArray([1577080200000, 157.5599, 157.4902, 157.495, 78330]);
```